# Vim stuck with message left from installing nokogiri

Tags: ruby, vim, rubygems, nokogiri

So I have the weirdest thing going on. I was installing `nokogiri` ruby gem and upon installation it displayed to the terminal an information message about certain things related to the installation. But everything went smooth.

Problem is, every time I try to open vim in the terminal now, this message pops up. Only when I press Ctrl+C on it, it closes and vim goes on to load.

If I uninstall the gem, vim starts working as usual. If I install it again, the message on vim startup comes back. What is this and how do I fix it?

EDIT:
to be precise, this is what happens in the terminal after I launch vim:

```
$ vim
Building nokogiri using system libraries.


^C
```

Comment: And… what does that message say?

Comment: Two questions. 1. Do you get the same message if you start without any plugins using `vim -u NONE -U NONE` ? 2. DO you get the same message if you start a new terminal instance?

Answer (score 0):

By the message it tries to build extensions to nokogiri gem. You may either wait until finished as the compilation takes some time (several minutes on my machine). It's built only once so you shouldn't get bothered next time.
You may also try to install nokogiri with extensions already built and/or properly configured to use system libraries instead of packaged-in.

Another option is to disable vim's plugin which tries to load ruby's repl.